# Laravel, получение body params action-а

Tags: php, laravel

Хочу написать пакет для автогенерации сваггера, или что-то вроде того.

Так вот, собственно вопрос:

Я хочу получить body params получив правила валидации Request-а, и уже их парсить

Через ReflectionClass я не увидел возможности получения этих данных.

Пробую создать entity реквеста, и, соответственно получаю ошибку входных данных.

```
/**
 * Parse entity data
 *
 * @param ReflectionClass $entity
 * @param array $params
 * @return array
 */
public function parse($entity, array $params = []): array
{
   $request = resolve($entity->getName());

   dd($request);
}
```

Ошибка:

```
  Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException  : The given data was invalid.
```

Можно ли как-то обойти валидацию и получить массив rules?

Может знаете более подходящий способ.

Думал еще парсить файл реквеста и так доставать рулы, но это уже последний из вариантов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось достать вот таким способом:

```
/**
 * Parse entity data
 *
 * @param ReflectionClass $entity
 * @param array $params
 * @return array
 */
public function parse($entity, array $params = []): array
{
    try {
        $request = resolve($entity->getName());
    }catch (ValidationException $exception){
        dd($exception->validator->getRules());
    }
}
```

Возвращает массив рулов